# Import XML into Orange3 using Python script

Tags: python, xml, orange

I have an xml document in my computer that look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF-8"?>
<IPDatas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/...>
   <datas>
      <dna>
         <profile>
            <loci>
               <locus name="one">
                  <allele order="1">10</allele>
                  <allele order="2">12.3</allele>
               </locus>
               <locus name="two">
                  <allele order="1">11.1</allele>
                  <allele order="2">17</allele>
               </locus>
               <locus name="three">
                  <allele order="1">13.2</allele>
                  <allele order="2">12.3</allele>
               </locus>
            </loci>
         </profile>
      </dna>
   </datas>
</IPdatas>
```

I want to import the document into Orange without first converting it outside Orange, so I probably need to use the "Python script" widget. After importing, I want to convert it into a table like this:

| one_1 | one_2 | two_1 | two_2 | three_1 | three_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 12.3 | 11.1 | 17 | 13.2 | 12.3 |

My knowledge of Python is poor, so any advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pprint


xml = '''
<IPDatas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/...">
   <datas>
      <dna>
         <profile>
            <loci>
               <locus name="one">
                  <allele order="1">10</allele>
                  <allele order="2">12.3</allele>
               </locus>
               <locus name="two">
                  <allele order="1">11.1</allele>
                  <allele order="2">17</allele>
               </locus>
               <locus name="three">
                  <allele order="1">13.2</allele>
                  <allele order="2">12.3</allele>
               </locus>
            </loci>
         </profile>
      </dna>
   </datas>
</IPDatas> '''

data = {}
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
locus_lst = root.findall('.//locus')
for locus in locus_lst:
    name = locus.attrib['name']
    allele_lst = locus.findall('allele')
    for allele in allele_lst:
        final_name = f"{name}_{allele.attrib['order']}"
        value = float(allele.text)
        data[final_name] = value
pprint.pprint(data)
```

output (a dict that you should be able to use with Orange)

```
{'one_1': 10.0,
 'one_2': 12.3,
 'three_1': 13.2,
 'three_2': 12.3,
 'two_1': 11.1,
 'two_2': 17.0}
```

Comment: That solves 90% of my problem! The only thing is that instead of copy/paste the xml's text into the script, I want to interactively choose the xml file, or maybe put the xml file in a specific folder and have the script take it from there. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: see the answer here https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html. Look for `tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')`